# Utilisation des articles en français

Tags: grammaire, articles

Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait m'expliquer la différence entre

- La liste des utilisateurs
- Une liste des utilisateurs
- La liste d'utilisateurs
- Une liste d'utilisateurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- La liste des utilisateurs
  La liste est définie, ainsi que les utilisateurs.
  Par exemple: "Apportez-moi la liste des utilisateurs de ce logiciel que nous avons établie hier". Nous savons tous les deux de quelle liste je parle.
- Une liste des utilisateurs
  Les utilisateurs sont définis mais pas la liste. Par exemple: "Pourriez-vous me rédiger une liste des utilisateurs de ce logiciel". La liste n'existe pas encore, mais les utilisateurs sont bien connus.
- La liste d'utilisateurs
  La liste est définie mais pas les utilisateurs. Par exemple: "Voici la liste d'utilisateurs de ce logiciel". Nous savons de quelle liste il est question, mais elle pourrait être incomplète (si la liste complète est trop longue et qu'on a besoin que de quelques utilisateurs).
- Une liste d'utilisateurs
  Les deux sont indéfinis. Par exemple: "J'ai besoin d'une liste d'utilisateurs." La liste n'existe pas encore et on ne demande pas nécessairement d'avoir tous les utilisateurs, seulement une partie.

Comment: "*Une liste*" peut aussi vouloir dire qu'elle existe, mais qu'il y a plus d'une. Exemple : "*Mes enfants ont tous **une** liste de cadeaux pour le père noël*" : Ils ont chacun une liste, et elles sont différentes. Si on avait dit "*..ont tous **la** liste...*" ça voudrait dire qu'ils ont chacun un exemplaire de **la même** liste. (C'est la même chose en anglais d'ailleurs)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, bien vu. Même si dans votre cas, je dirais "Mes enfants on tous leur liste de cadeaux...".

Comment: J'ai pris le premier exemple que j'ai trouvé. C'est vrai la liste au père Noël est un cas particulier puisque chaque enfant n'en a qu'une.